# Multi datasource using AbstractRoutingDatasource with Spring jdbc template

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-jdbc

I am working on a requirement for multi-tenant application which should support mulitple datasources. I have used `AbstractRoutingDataSource` for the JPA repositories, now I need to extend it to spring jdbc template for a new application. Is there any reference/example that can be used for reference?

Comment: just add `spring-boot-starter-data-jdbc` dependency, and you are up & ready! (now only need some queries, "entities", tests..) official (boot-less) reference doc (chapter "getting started"): https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jdbc/docs/current/reference/html/#jdbc.getting-started

Comment: spring boot (reference doc) refers very brief to it: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/data.html#data.sql.jdbc, here is the relevant (spring-boot) "auto config": https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/main/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc

Comment: ..and last but not least, the official samples: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-examples/tree/main/jdbc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this article.  [baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-abstract-routing-data-source)

Having configured the AbstractRoutingDataSource with the actual data source instances, it's a simple case of then wiring the AbstractRoutingDataSource into the JdbcTemplate instance and also into the TransactionManager.  JdbcTemplate is thread safe and when you perform an operation against the single JdbcTemplate instance, the datasource that is used will be based on the datasource that was set on the context holder for the executing thread.